# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error? Boost Multithreading/Mutex Exception

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex, unlock

I seem to be having difficulty understanding what is wrong with my code below. The program runs correctly, but at the line

```
startCounter.join();
```

My program seems to crash, with a error code EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, address=0x0). I am using XCode.

Everything up until that line works correctly; the program prints out the value of n each second as another thread increments the value indefinitely. What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::mutex mtx;

class Worker
{
public:
    Worker(int n);
    void increment();
    void printValue();
private:
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    Worker test(5);

    boost::thread startCounter(boost::bind(&Worker::increment, &test));
    std::cout << "Increment Thread Started..." << std::endl;

    boost::thread startPrinter(boost::bind(&Worker::printValue, &test));
    std::cout << "Print Thread Started..." << std::endl;

    startPrinter.join();
    startCounter.join();

    std::cout << "Program Complete." << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Worker::Worker(int n) : n(n)
{
    std::cout << "Initial Value: " << n << std::endl;
}

void Worker::increment()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 60000000; i++) {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mtx);
        n = i;
    }

    std::cout << "Increment Thread Finished. Final Value: " << n << "." << std::endl;
}

void Worker::printValue()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mtx);
            std::cout << "Current value: " << n << std::endl;
        }
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
    }

    std::cout << "Print Thread Finished." << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps "`address=0x0`" might be a clue :)?

Comment: startPrinter.join() uses the member function from the "test" object, right? That object still exists when the function is called... Unless I'm missing something quite blatantly simple.

Comment: For starters, you should be calling `startCounter.join();` as well to keep its destructor from being called while it is still joinable.

Comment: @UrNotSorry: are you posting the real code?  The example now no longer has the `startCounter.join();` call in it (which is where the question says the exception is thrown).  If you're posting something different than what throws the exception, it might be difficult to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake... I accidentally left out the startCounter.join() line when I edited the code. It's there now, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @UrNotSorry: given that the location of `startCounter.join()` (and some other details) in the posted code has changed, is it possible that there are really two calls to `startCounter.join()` in the code you're compiling?  Maybe the intended call to `startPrinter.join()` is mistyped or a copy/paste error?

Comment: The code above is my complete program. I've checked that both join() functions are called only once, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: how are you building this program? Any optimizations? What version of boost? I built and ran your sample code using gcc 4.2.1 and boost 1.46 without issue on my mac.